# jquery validation show error message on correct data on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Hi have a form where I have applied the jquery validation plugin. Everything works well until I come to submit the form.  What the form does is that it checks the username and email address to what is stored in the database and if the username or email is taken, an error message is displayed. This is done when the form element loses focus.

So what I do is I change the username to a username that is stored in the db and an error message is returned, which is correct. I then change the username to a unique value and the error message disappears.

Now when I come to submit the form, an error message is displayed on the username that is not unique.

so if I change my username to be **ericy@sa2** error is displayed, I change to **danny@sa** which removes the error and then when I submit the form the error message pops up that **ericy@sa2** is not unique and clearly the form element contains **danny@sa**

Here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $( "#manageAdministratorForm" ).validate({
        onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
        rules: {
            "name": "required",
            "menuAccess[]": "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "index.php?action=MANAGE_ADMINISTRATORS_FORM",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function(){
                            return $('#email').val();
                        },
                        adminId: function() {
                           return $('#adminId').val();
                        },
                        subAction: "validateEmail"
                    }

                }
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "index.php?action=MANAGE_ADMINISTRATORS_FORM",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        username: function(){
                            return $('#username').val();
                        },
                        adminId: function() {
                            return $('#adminId').val();
                        },
                        subAction: "validateUsername"
                    }

                }
            },
            newPassword: {
                minlength: 8
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                equalTo: "#newPassword"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": "A name must be entered for the administrator",
            "menuAccess[]": "Menu items must be assigned to an administrator",
            "username": {
                required: "A username must be entered for the administrator",
                remote: function() { return $.validator.format("Username {0} is already taken", $("#username").val())}
            },
            "email": {
                required: "An email must be entered for the administrator",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                remote: function() { return $.validator.format("Email {0} is already taken", $("#email").val())}
            },
            "newPassword": {
                minlength: "Enter at least {0} characters for your password"
            },
            "confirmPassword": {
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }

        },
        errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
        errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
        wrapper: 'li',
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var $form = $(form);
                $form.submit();
            }    


    });
});
```